# AddEventListener from object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have created an object which includes many action for nested Sortable, to order or modify my categories. Currently the object is like this.

```
var CategoriesIndexView = {
options: {
    baseIndent: 10,
    defaultIndent: 38,
    etc...
},
data: {},
events: {
    "click button.collapsible-trigger": "toggleNestedRow",
    "change #bulk-action-menu": "performBulkAction",
    "click a.category-visible": "toggleCategoryVisibility",
    "click #IndexDeleteButton": "bulkDelete"
},
initialize: function() {
    this.bindNestedSortable()
},
bindNestedSortable: function() {
    var a = this,
        b = null;
    $(".SortableList").nestedSortable(options);
},
toggleNestedRow: function(a){
    var b = $(a.currentTarget),
        c = $("i.la", b),
        d = !c.hasClass("la-plus");
    d ? this.expandCategory(b) : this.collapseCategory(b)
},
expandCategory: function(a) {},
...etc
```

I want to addEventListeners, based on the "events" array, i saw that on BackView.exteds method, but i am using simple javascript. Can i add the EventListeners based on "events", inside CategoriesIndexView? It is important for the Listeners to be inside the object because all other functions use "this" of the object.

Comment: Check out **`Function.prototype.bind`** on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: Do the values of the properties within object at `events` property of `CategoriesIndexView` reference function names?

Comment: functions inside CategoriesIndexView

Comment: Properties reference Methods inside CategoriesIndexView

Comment: On initialize i used, jquery bind..
$("button.collapsible-trigger").bind("click", this.toggleNestedRow);
which calls the property toggleNestedRow, but inside the property i call another property but triggers an error "this.expandCategory is not a function"

Comment: Bind is old jquery, use `on`. However that being said I have no real clue what you want to do. May I suggest creating a jsfiddle with a simple example.

Comment: Why is event type and selector within property name?

Comment: This part was taken from another site, so i tried to implement it on my nestedSortable. The whole thing was to create a JS "class" with methods and properties in order to control edit of the category menu within the class. I wanted to show the submenu after clicking the button to collapse which is generated by an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't us the event property with values, but on initialisation i used jQuery .on and captured the event to return event.currentTarget.

like this

```
$("button.collapsible-trigger").on("click", function(event){
  a.toggleNestedRow( event );
});
```

works fine